# DataTables is changing the width of columns with ajax sourced data in a Bootstrap 3.3.7 application

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

My application is using:

- DataTables 1.10.16
- Bootstrap 3.3.7
- jQuery 3.2.1

**Scenario:**

I'm trying to add form inputs to the headings on a table to allow searching by 2 columns. This is a custom feature of my application; it is **not** the search facility that DataTables provides.

**Problem:**

I want the search inputs to appear full width of each column. I want it to look like this:

[image]

But it's being rendered like this - notice that the search inputs have reduced in width:

[image]

*(The table data is blurred due to it being a private application).*

The markup I've used is based on Bootstrap's column system - I've used 2 `.col-md-6` so the `<th>` elements are equal width:

```
<table id="regulatoryInformationTable" class="table responsive display table-striped pb-25" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <th class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Regulation Name">
            </div>
        </th>
        <th class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Regulation Data">
            </div>
        </th>
    </thead>
</table>
```

If I open the page with this markup it renders as per the first screenshot - but without any data in the table - as I haven't made the ajax request and updated the DataTable at this point.

When I make the ajax request, the table is populated, but then the inputs seem to shrink in width. My js to use DataTables and make the ajax request is as follows:

```
$(function() {

    /* Populate table of Regulatory Information */
    var regulatoryInformationTable = $('#regulatoryInformationTable').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "searching": false,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/get-data.json",
            "method": "POST",
            "cache": false,
            "dataSrc": function (json) {
                return json.data;
            }
        },
        "columns": [
            {"data": "display_label", "name": "display_label"},
            {"data": "display_value", "name": "display_value"},
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            {"width": "50%", "targets": 0},
            {"width": "50%", "targets": 1},
            {"orderable": false, "targets": [0,1]} // Can't order
        ],
        "paging": false, // no pagination
        "language": {
            "zeroRecords": "Sorry we no data for this substance",
            "infoFiltered": "",
            "infoEmpty": "",
            "processing": '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw"></i>'
        }
    });   
});
```

I had used the `columnDefs` array to specify `width: 50%` but this doesn't make any difference - even if I remove it.

Can anyone advise how to fix this?

Comment: Can you post jsfiddle with reproducible issue? My jsfiddle is working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/cy8Lzbhn/

Comment: Your jsfiddle isn't working at all. When I open the page it does an alert: `DataTables warning: table id=regulatoryInformationTable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7`

Comment: I forgot to update my fiddle, check it out now: https://jsfiddle.net/cy8Lzbhn/10/

Comment: @DipenShah please can you post this as an answer instead of a comment? With some explanation of what you've done. I can't see what's been changed but it does seem to work on the jsfiddle. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the width of the parent and how will 50% width will suffice, as the _th_ tag is already sharing 50% of the width each, as percentage is always relative to the parent right. and try to check **col-md-6** and **form-control** class properties.

Answer (score 3):

me too facing the same issue couple of week before if you dont want to auto width add,

```
table {
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
```

}

so this flicker wont appear.because its basic table feature to adjust the td size from content.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that DataTables sets the `width` of the `th` to a fixed value.
This should cut the inputs inside.
Try to disable the `autoWidth` option. Leave others options as You defined.

```
$('#regulatoryInformationTable').dataTable( {
  "autoWidth": false,
} );
```

Ref: https://datatables.net/reference/option/autoWidth

Do not use the `col-*` Bootstrap class on tables, let tables flow free, these classes are intended for layouts.

Comment: I've tried `autoWidth` already and it didn't fix the issue. I also removed the `.col-md-6` classes from the `<th>` and that didn't help either. It's something to do with using ajax sourced data because if I have the table populated on page load, or don't put any data inside `<tbody>` the heading widths render correctly.

Comment: Can You set up fake data in order to do a test? Anyway seems related to the DataTables render behavior. Should also help a screenshot of the inspector in that zone.

Answer (score 1):

Check out following code snippet where datatable is working as expected:

```js
$(function() {
    /* Populate table of Regulatory Information */
    var regulatoryInformationTable = $('#regulatoryInformationTable').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "searching": false,
        "ajax": {
          "url": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums",
            "method": "GET",
            "cache": false,
            "dataSrc": function (json) {
                return json;
            }
        },
        "columns": [
            {"data": "id", "name": "id"},
            {"data": "title", "name": "title"},
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            {"width": "50%", "targets": 0},
            {"width": "50%", "targets": 1},
            {"orderable": false, "targets": [0,1]} // Can't order
        ],
        "paging": false, // no pagination
        "language": {
            "zeroRecords": "Sorry we no data for this substance",
            "infoFiltered": "",
            "infoEmpty": "",
            "processing": '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw"></i>'
        }
    });   
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<table id="regulatoryInformationTable" class="table responsive display table-striped pb-25" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <th class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Regulation Name">
            </div>
        </th>
        <th class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Regulation Data">
            </div>
        </th>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cy8Lzbhn/10/) if you prefer.

**Explaination:**

I have used your original code and modified few bits so that I can post a working demo here. Only things I have changed are api to get data and required CSS and javascript files. I'm using api from [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) for demonstration and have modified columns based on api response structure.

Comment: I don't understand the explanation. I understand you've changed the source of the ajax data. But what else has changed? It looks like exactly the same js, using the same libraries and doesn't have any custom CSS. So I can't understand what I need to change to make this work on mine, since effectively it's the same except the source of the data?

Comment: @Andy For start can you match order of css, that might make a huge difference. Second thing is create a plain old html file with mine and your code and compare them using diff tool to see what are the changes exactly and you might be able to find out what is going on.